# How to get name of derived class from base class

Tags: python

I can get the name of a base class as follows:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     pass
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     def print_base(self):
...         for base in self.__class__.__bases__:
...             print base.__name__
...
>>> foo = Derived()
>>> foo.print_base()
Base
```

In this example, how do I do the reverse and get the name of `Derived` from a function within `Base`? E.g:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def print_derived(self):
...         [pseudocode: return Derived class name]
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     pass
...
>>> bar = Derived()
>>> bar.print_derived()
Derived
```

I could obviously just print `self.__class__.__name___` in `Derived` but I have a lot of unit tests inheriting `Base` as a mixin and I want to track which class called it from one adjustment to the `Base` mixin.

Comment: Printing `self.__class__.__name___` in the method in Base should print `Derived` if called from an instance of `Derived`, is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to print `self.__class__` in the `Base` method:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def print_derived(self):
...         print(self.__class__.__name__)
...
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     pass
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d.print_derived()
Derived
```